# What effects does restarting a listening socket have on accepted connections?

Tags: sockets, posix

According to POSIX, when a process `accept()`s connections on a `listen()`ing `socket()` L1, and afterwards `close()`s L1, and creates a new `socket()` L2 bound on the same interface/address/port, `listen()`s and `accept()`s new connections, will the sockets accepted from the previous listening socket L1 operate properly as if L1 had not been closed? Or is creating and starting socket L2 in this manner impossible in the first place? Please provide a reference.

Example:

```c
int server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
bind(server, &someAddress, sizeof(someAddress)))
listen(server, 0);
int conn_1 = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
/* ... */
int conn_n = accept(server, NULL, NULL);

/* RESTART LISTENING SOCKET: */
close(server);
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
bind(server, &someAddress, sizeof(someAddress)))
listen(server, 0);
int newconn_1 = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
/* ... */
int newconn_n = accept(server, NULL, NULL);

/* Will connections conn_1...conn_n still properly operate at this point?
```

Comment: You need to add some code to illustrate your point. I couldn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @SergeyA How about the example I now added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect usage of `socket()` notwithstanding - the first argument should be an address famility, not a protocol family, and hence AF_INET - the code will work as expected.

Once `accept()` returns a new socket, it is completely independent from the listening socket, and is not affected by it.

Comment: Fixed the `socket()` argument.

Comment: Is it also independent from a new listening socket created with the same binding? E.g. if both old and new sockets bind to TCP port 12345 on 0.0.0.0 on all interfaces?

Comment: @jotik, doesn't matter. It is socket on it's own now.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: There is no specific reference for that. It is just the absence of any reference about the dependency. For example, this is from man `accept()`: *On success, these system calls return a non-negative integer that  is  a  descriptor for  the accepted socket.* it doesn't say anything about parent socket, so we assume it is independent.